# Sage 300 intelligence reporting not working for admin user

Tags: sage-300

All the required configuration are done for the intelligence reporting and it's works for other users on portal but for admin user it's not showing the Intelligence report menu? I am stuck over there can any one help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set AllowWebApiAccessForAdmin Key as true [From Sage Support Document](https://support.na.sage.com/selfservice/viewdocument.do?noCount=true&externalId=84722&sliceId=1&cmd=&ViewedDocsListHelper=com.kanisa.apps.common.BaseViewedDocsListHelperImpl)

```
 <add key="AllowWebApiAccessForAdmin" value="true" />
```